# Map arbitrary relations via Neo4j OGM

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Neo4j OGM supports arbitrary node properties being mapped to entity classes via `@Convert` and `CompositeAttributeConverter` but what about the relation part? How would I map arbitrary relations in a `@NodeEntity`?

The actual properties and relations being used in my data model are configurable, i.e. they are not known at compile time. Example: Configuration specifies nodes of label A and B and a relation from A to B named REL_1. Now when I am querying nodes of label A then I would like to retrieve and map the relations in the corresponding resulting node entity.

I tried to build cypher queries depending on the configuration but I am stuck at retrieving relations whose end node should be mapped by OGM. Here is my simplified generated query structure:

```
MATCH (n:A) RETURN n, [(n)-[rn:REL_1]-(n2) | [rn, n2]]
```

I also tried

```
MATCH (n:A) RETURN n, [[(n)-[rn:REL_1]-(n2) | [rn, n2]]]
```

which is the same pattern as is generated by OGM when calling `session.load` with a fixed data model. However, both queries do not map `n2` in the result of `session.query` call. Instead the returned type for `n2` is a `NodeModel` but I don't want to map it myself because OGM is already capable to do it. **What's wrong with my query? Or is this a bug?**

Note: This query would do the trick but that feels like an odd workaround.

```
MATCH (n:A) RETURN n, [(n)-[rn:REL_1]-() | rn], [(n)-[:REL_1]-(n2) | n2]
```

I am using Neo4J 3.5 with OGM 3.2.3 included via Sprint Boot 2.2.2.

Comment: The `de` in your queries is not defined. Did you mean `n`?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Filed an issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/737

Comment: This issue has been fixed with OGM 3.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to an idiosyncrasy of the [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) implementation.

Does this more straightforward Cypher query work for you?

```
MATCH (n:A)-[rn:REL_1]-(n2) RETURN n, COLLECT({rn: rn, n2: n2})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `n2` is still not mapped by OGM. Also, this query structure would imply a lot of changes to my queries. I will file an issue on github OGM project, let's see if they confirm it as bug. However, thanks for your proposals!